# Spring-jms Getting Connection from DMLC

Tags: spring, connection, wso2, listener, spring-jms

i'm almost new with Spring-JMS.
I m facing up to the configuration connecting my spring application to WSO2 Message Broker.
This is the code i used:

Code:

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="qpidConnectionfactory">
    <jee:environment>
            java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
        connectionfactory.qpidConnectionfactory=amqp://admin:admin@carbon/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5673'
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>


<bean id="errorHandler" class="it.innovapuglia.sistemapuglia.diogene.spring.subscriber.ErrorH" />
<bean id="messageHandler" class="it.innovapuglia.sistemapuglia.diogene.spring.subscriber.SpringSubscriber" />
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
    destination-type="topic"
    container-type="default" 
    acknowledge="auto" concurrency="3-3"
    error-handler="errorHandler" >
    <jms:listener destination="LEGGI_ATTRIBUTI_DOCUMENTO" ref="messageHandler"  />
</jms:listener-container>
```

is there the possibility to use DMLC subclassing it and to get the running connection in the way i can catch Connection Exception?
If yes in what way?

Answer (score 0):

`createConnection()` is on `JmsAccessor` (a superclass of the DMLC).

Or, you can just register your ExceptionListener with the DMLC and it will be invoked for `JmsException`.

If you go the subclass route, supply your class name in the `container-class` attribute.